# Resteasy Client Http caching

Tags: caching, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-caching

i am trying to configure my Resteasy Client for clientside http caching. I'd like to have a persistent cache on the client side, which survives a restart of my client application. With the help of google i was able to setup up my Resteasy Client like this:

```
File cacheDir = new File("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\cache");
CacheConfig config = CacheConfig.DEFAULT;
FileResourceFactory resourceFactory = new FileResourceFactory(cacheDir);
ManagedHttpCacheStorage cacheStorage = new ManagedHttpCacheStorage(config);
CloseableHttpClient client = CachingHttpClients.custom()
            .setCacheConfig(config)
            .setResourceFactory(resourceFactory)
            .setHttpCacheStorage(cacheStorage)
            .setDeleteCache(false)
            .build();
ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(client);
ResteasyClient rclient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().httpEngine(engine).build();
```

I can see that the Resteasy Client is using a caching mechanism. When invoking a request twice, the second request is way faster then the first one. However, the cache does not get persisted when shutting the client. Furthermore there is never a file written in the specified directory, when setting up the client. Is there something i am missing? I need the cache to be restored from the filesystem after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code without the resteasy layer, the httpclient successfully stored a file in the cache directory for each request that was dispatched. An expected error was thrown when the cache directory does not exist.

As for the recovery of the cache on restart, it seems that the `ManagedHttpCacheStorage` is not designed to recover cached entries on restart, so it does store to the file system, when used with `FileResourceFactory`, but does not load from the file system.

So, only `memcached` implementation seems provide this feature, of cached object survival on application restart, while `ehcache` seems to not provide this feature in the open-source project.